# JBoss Log File Maintenance/Cleanup

Tags: configuration, logging, jboss

I am running JBoss 4.0.2 server and over the years it has created a large number of log files that I would like to clean up.

I would like to keep the same logging level but also have it delete any log files older than 3 months.

Is there a way to do that in the configuration or should I just write a perl script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in a cron job:

```
find /var/log/jbossas/default/ -mtime +90 | xargs rm -f
```

See more on the [unix find](http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/Find/find_mini_tutorial.shtml) command

We also run the following in order to save disk space. It compresses all files who are at least 3 days old

```
find /var/log/jbossas/default/ -mtime +3 -name \*.log | xargs bzip2
```

Comment: I looked up the command and it looks like it will solve my problem if I just make it -mtime +90.